# Google Maps Android api v2 polyline length

Tags: java, android, google-maps, polyline

I'm trying to find the android maps api v2 method that will determine the length of the polyline that I am creating while I am moving. I would put it inside onLocationChanged() for continual updates. Anyone know what the method is and what units the the maps api will display the length?

```
Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions());


public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {



line.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())
 .width(5)
 .color(Color.RED));

}
```

Comment: do you want to draw your path when device move ?

Comment: @mohammedmomn I just need the length of the polyline that's created as I move. Yes I want it to draw the path, but more importantly I need the path length. Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479667/how-can-i-calculate-a-current-distance-to-polyline-points-on-google-maps-v2-in-a) can help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [Location.distanceBetween](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29) on your last location to your current location. If you want a total distance from your start and end positions then keep a running total as your location changes

Comment: This is what I did not want to do. Imagine a case where my car is on a no network zone for a while. The whole calculation will go wrong. Isnt there a direct api which takes a list of points and then give a distance

Comment: Why does it matter if you have an internet connection or not `distanceBetween` does not make a network call

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. Here is how I was able to solve it.

1. `private ArrayList<LatLng> mLatLngList;`
   Add the location to the ArrayList on Location change.
2. Use Gradle to import this http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/ library into your project or
   `compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'`
3. Import the library `import com.google.maps.android.SphericalUtil;`
4. `double distance = SphericalUtil.computeLength(mLatLngList);`

Comment: This is should be ranked as the valid answer

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question.  Here is my solution where points is the PolylineOptions object.

```
protected float calculateMiles() {
    float totalDistance = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < points.getPoints().size(); i++) {
        Location currLocation = new Location("this");
        currLocation.setLatitude(points.getPoints().get(i).latitude);
        currLocation.setLongitude(points.getPoints().get(i).longitude);

        Location lastLocation = new Location("this");
        currLocation.setLatitude(points.getPoints().get(i-1).latitude);
        currLocation.setLongitude(points.getPoints().get(i-1).longitude);

        totalDistance += lastLocation.distanceTo(currLocation);


    }

    return totalDistance;
}
```

Comment: and where is `.distanceTo` defined?

Comment: It's defined in the location object https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)

Comment: You need to multiply  it with EARTH_RADIUS . check computeLength method  https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java